# What does "=;" mean in bash?

Tags: bash

I am new to bash and just ran into

```
local name=; name = $("something", "something")
```

Can someone please explain what =; means?

I have tried to google it, but cannot find any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local name=; ...
```

Define a local variable (i.e. only known to the funcion) named `name` and set it to the empty string. The assignment is redundant in this code snippet, since new variables always have the null string assigned.

```
....; name = $("something", "something")
```

Invoke a command named `name` and pass it several parameters. The first parameter is an equal sign. No special meaning of `=`. Note however that we also have:

```
name=$("something", "something")
```

Execute a child process, running command `something` with parameter *something*, and assign the standard output of the execution to variable `name`; and:

```
name=something1 something2
```

which means to execute a command named `something2` in an environment, where the **environment** variable `name` is set to *something1*. In the calling process, `name` does not change its value. Therefore,

```
name=1
name=2 printenv name
echo $name
```

would print

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You know that `;` is a command separator?

It's the same here. Instead of writing the two commands on a single line, it could be split into two lines:

```
local name=
name=$("something", "something")
```

Answer (score 0):

`=;` does not mean anything. It is a `=` followed by a `;`.

The semicolon (`;`) is the command separator. A newline does the same thing.

Your code is equivalent to:

```bash
local name=
name=...
```

`local` declares a local variable in a function. The first statement declares the local variable `name` and initializes it with nothing. The same effect is produced by `local name` without any initialization.

---

#### Remark

In the question, the second statement has spaces around the `=` sign.
The spaces are word separators. With spaces, that line is not an assignment but an invocation of the command `name` with two arguments: the `=` sign and the output of the command enclosed in `$(` and `)`.

There should be no spaces around `=` for an assignment.